# NH3.2 Mapping By Code using 'where' clause

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I've tried to define many-to-many relation with 'where' clause using `MappingByCode` from `NH3.2`, but I don't know how can I do it.

With `FluentNHibernate` I can use the `ChildWhere()` method:

```
 public class ProcedureMap : ClassMap<Procedure>
 {
        public ProcedureMap()
        {
            this.HasManyToMany(a => a.FormTemplates).ChildWhere("IsDeleted = 0").AsSet();
        }
 }
```

This code will generate next HBM:

```
 <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="Procedure" table="Procedure">
    <set name="FormTemplates" table="ProceduresToFormTemplates">
      <key foreign-key="FK_Procedures_FormTemplates">
        <column name="ProcedureId" />
      </key>
      <many-to-many class="FormTemplate" where="IsDeleted = 0">
        <column name="FormTemplateId" />
      </many-to-many>
    </set>
  </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

How can I get same mapping using `MappingByCode` from `NH3.2`?

Answer (score 0):

You would use the filter method on the many to many mapping.

```
this.Bag(
   x => x.Procedure,
   m =>
     {
         m.Table("Procedure");
         m.Key(k => k.Column("ProcedureId"));
         m.Filter("NoDeleted", mapper => mapper.Condition("IsDeleted = 0"));
     },
   x => x.ManyToMany(
           map =>
                {
                    map.Column("FormTemplateId");
                }));
```