# Convert XML mappings to Code Mapping for ISET of ManyToMany

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I am presently working on one of the project, where I need to convert the xml mappings to code mappings.

I have a ISET collection with Many to Many along with where clause. I had done the code mappings but where to put the where clause in code mappings ?

```
<set inverse="true" name="SystemRoles" table="UserPriv" mutable="true">
    <cache usage="read-write" />
    <key>
        <column name="UserID" />
    </key>
    <many-to-many
       class="SampleProject.Domain.SystemRole, SampleProject.Domain"
       where="PrivilegeType = 'SystemRole'">
        <column name="PrivilegeID" />
    </many-to-many>
</set>
```

And my Code mappings :

```
Set(x => x.SystemRoles, m =>
    {
        m.Schema("dbo");
        m.Table("UserPriv");
        m.Inverse(true);
        m.Key(k => k.Column("UserId"));
        m.Cascade(Cascade.None);
    }, col => col.ManyToMany(p =>
    {
        p.Column(x => x.Name("PrivilegeId"));
    })
    );
```

Where should I put : `where="PrivilegeType = 'SystemRole'"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **where** should belong to `many-to-many` as in the `xml` mapping

```
Set(x => x.SystemRoles, m =>
    {
        // set mapping
    }, 
    col => col.ManyToMany(p =>
    {
        // mapping of the many-to-many
        p.Column(x => x.Name("PrivilegeId"));
        p.Where("PrivilegeType = 'SystemRole'");
    })
    );
```

*But not fully sure, if all features are already supported in mapping by code...*

*Some more "documentation" http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-onetomany-and-other.html by Adam Bar*

EXTEND, check the https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/releasenotes.txt

and for [Build 4.0.0.Alpha1](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/releasenotes.txt#L302)

> - [NH-2997] - Where() clause with many-to-many relation is missing (solution in description)

Comment: can you look if this solution will work ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714307/nh3-2-mapping-by-code-using-where-clause

Comment: There is a **where** .. I just tested... which version of NHibernate are you using? Do you have the latest ?

Comment: In which version you tested ? I am in v 3.3

Comment: There are realse notes: Build 4.0.0.Alpha1 .... * [NH-2997] - Where() clause with many-to-many relation is missing (solution in description)
* so you should upgrade.. and all is solved! ;) that is great is not it?

Comment: yes that is and we are planning to upgrade. But the major change is we are using Iesi collections but Nh 4 is using inbuilt so lot of major change

Comment: I see.. do not give up please. NHiberante 4.0+ is really great tool ;)